# Passing through Txt file formatted like Json

Tags: python, json

A new Python learner and now having this problem where I have this text file formatted in Json a-like.

It looks something like this:

> '[{"attempt":"9","email":"abc@gmail.com","event":"deferred","ip":"123.117.56.543"},\n{"attempt":"6","email":"123@yahoo.com","event":"deferred","ip":"123.117.56.242"}]\n'

- My task is to get the email and IP out from each {} and create a
  table.

currently i am thinking to:

> convert this txt file to JSON and get the
> info out, however, please if you know any better approach, it'd be
> very much appreciated.

Secondly,

> if i am not wrong, can someone suggest a
> direction to do it, because right now i don't know where to
> start.

I have tried:

```
with open("file.TXT") as file:
file_contents = [x.strip(',\n') for x in file.readlines()]
```

then try **json.dumps()** but it didn't work.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your input looks like in YAML format, so using yaml standard library should be a most "pythonic" way of handling this problem.

So first, install a pyyaml library

```
pip install pyyaml
```

and then getting a ip should be quite simple.

```
import yaml
data = '[{"attempt":"9","email":"abc@gmail.com","event":"deferred","ip":"123.117.56.543"},\n{"attempt":"6","email":"123@yahoo.com","event":"deferred","ip":"123.117.56.242"}]' 
data = yaml.load(data)
print(data[0]['ip'])
```

or directly from file

```
import yaml
with open('file.TXT') as f:  
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an almost json file. Start by reading it into a variable, strip the endline, remove the brackets, and then use json.loads:

```
with open(file_path) as f:
    txt = f.read()
    stripped = txt.strip()
    no_brackets = stripped.strip('[]')
    mydict = json.loads(no_brackets)
```